# Delete several lines from a file using grep

Tags: bash, files, scripting

I have a file with multiple lines which looks like that :

brand,model,inches,price

```
dell       xps      13    9000     
macbook    pro      13    13000
asus       zenbook  13    10500
```

I want to delete the lines where the price is more than 10000. I want to ask if it is possible by using grep?

Comment: May the last field look like `08000` or `8999.90` or `1e8` or is it limited to well-behaved (without leading 0) decimal integer numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following to get the lines where price is greater than 10000 :

```
$ grep -E '.* [0]*[1-9][0-9]{4,}$' file.txt 
macbook    pro      13    13000
asus       zenbook  13    10500
```

If you want to remove those lines add `-v` :

```
$ grep -vE '.* [0]*[1-9][0-9]{4,}$' file.txt 
dell       xps      13    9000
```

- `.*` will match all characters upto the last column containing prices
- `[1-9]` will match the first digit of the price
- `[0-9]{4,}$` will match 4 or more digits after the first digit so we have a total of five digits meaning 10000 or greater

Answer (score 4):

It's possible, but `grep` uses regular expressions that operate on strings, not numbers.

```
grep -v '[0-9]\{5\}$' input.txt
```

`-v` removes the matching lines. `[0-9]` matches any digit, `\{n\}` means the preceding thing is repeated n times (5 times in this case, i.e. 10000 and more). `$` matches the line end.

`awk` can compare numbers, so it's more suitable for the job:

```
awk '$4<10000{print}' input.txt
```

or Perl:

```
perl -ane 'print if $F[-1] < 10000' input.txt
```

Comment: this will match 01234 too, check my answer..

Comment: I don't know if it's correct to say that `grep -v` deletes the matching lines. It simply inverts the matching so that it selects all non-matching lines.

Answer (score 2):

Given your sample input:

```
$ cat /tmp/foo
dell       xps      13    9000
macbook    pro      13    13000
asus       zenbook  13    10500
```

You can use awk:

```
$ awk '{ if ($4 <= 10000) print; }' /tmp/foo
dell       xps      13    9000
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
cp input.txt original.txt
awk 'NR==1 || $4 < 10000 ' original.txt > input.txt
```

where

- condition with NR==1 to keep header line.